# Possible loss of precision double

Tags: java, double-precision

```
int leccs1 = q1+q2+r1+swhw1;
System.out.println("LecCS = "+ leccs1+ "/60");
int lecprelim = lcp+lcpo;
System.out.println("LecPrelim = "+ lecprelim+ "/100");
double x = 0.50;
int lecgrade = ((x * leccs1) + (x * lecprelim));
System.out.println("LecGrade = "+ lecgrade);



C:\FINALS OBE\OBE1\ICS112_1ISB_LecFinals_OBE.java:61: error: possible loss of precision
    int lecgrade = ((x * leccs1) + (x * lecprelim));
                                 ^
  required: int
  found:    double
1 error

Process completed.
```

I am trying to compute grade. The user enters the grades as input. I want `x` to be double not int.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. `lecgrade` either needs to be a `double` or you need to explicity cast it to an `int` to truncate.

Comment: And x is already a double...

Answer (score 4):

change

```
   int lecgrade = ((x * leccs1) + (x * lecprelim));
```

to

```
double lecgrade = ((x * leccs1) + (x * lecprelim));

int grade=lecgrade.intValue();
```

or in a **single line** you can write

```
int lecgrade = ((x * leccs1) + (x * lecprelim)).intValue();
```

use `intValue()` to convert from `double` to `int`

check [**intValue()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

What i came to know is you want lecgrade as an int you can do this by type casting

Try this,

```
int lecgrade =(int) ((x * leccs1) + (x * lecprelim));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need lecgrade to be of type int, you probably want to apply some rounding before casting, e.g.:

```
        double lecgrade = 1.9d;

        int result = (int) lecgrade;
        int resultRounded = (int) Math.round(lecgrade);

        System.out.println(result); // prints 1
        System.out.println(resultRounded); // prints 2
```

Please note that

1. intValue() is not applicable to primitives, you'd have to box your value first
2. intValue() may truncate your value instead of rounding it

   ```
       Double k = Double.valueOf(1.9d);
       System.out.println(k.intValue()); // prints 1 for me
   ```